# National Instruments USB 6009 not recognizing digital channels in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nidaqmx

I am trying to use a National Instruments USB6009 with Matlab(2012a on Windows 7) using the Data Acquisition Toolbox, but when I look at the device it does not register any available digital channels:

```
daq.getDevices

ans = 

ni: National Instruments USB-6009 (Device ID: 'Dev1')
Analog input subsystem supports:
    8 ranges supported
    Rates from 0.1 to 48000.0 scans/sec
    8 channels ('ai0','ai1','ai2','ai3','ai4','ai5','ai6','ai7')
    'Voltage' measurement type

 Analog output subsystem supports:
    0 to +5.0 Volts range
    Rates from 0.0 to 0.0 scans/sec
    2 channels ('ao0','ao1')
    'Voltage' measurement type

 Counter input subsystem supports:
    Rates from 0.0 to 0.0 scans/sec
    1 channel ('ctr0')
    'EdgeCount' measurement type
```

I know this device has digital channels.  I have tried a backup USB 6008 and I get the same issue.

I have installed all the latest drivers from NI.  I have also tried "addDigitalChannel" but I receive an error stating that this is not possible for the given daq.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Eric

Comment: You might get an answer quicker if you use Matlab web site, it is a very specific question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with Matlab 2012a.  Upgrading to 2013b has solved this issue and now Matlab recognizes the digital channels on the NI USB6008/6009 DAQs.

Hopefully this  will be helpful should someone end up in the same situation.